# How do you provide specific answers to question prompts from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script provided by our admin to connect to HPC where I have to provide answers to various prompts every time I connect. Is there a way that I can put my answers in a text file and it provides the answers to the questions based on what question is asked? I tried other answers on SO but here the situation is different because our admin made the questions/options random and sometimes not all questions pop up. Therefor a static input like `echo "y n y y y"` won't work. Here is the full workflow.

I invoke the script as `login.sh` then prompt comes up

```
1) name1  2) name2   2) name3   4) name4 
Please select an account:
```

then I select the number 1 to 4 based on which one I want to connect to. But let's say I always want to connect to `name1`, and I can simply do that by passing `echo "1" | login.sh`. However, the tricky part is that these accounts do not appear in the same order each time. Sometimes `name1` is on 1, the next time on 4 and so on. It is random. How can I automate it in such a way that I always connect to `name1`?

Once I pass this first prompt then the next prompt similar to this one comes up

```
1) instance1 
2) instance2
3) instance3
4) random
Please select an instance to connect to:
```

then again I fill in one numeric value 1 to 4. I always want to connect to `random` but similar to above, it doesn't always come at position 4. How can I do it?

These first couple of steps are numerical but then comes a bit more complex where it asks us to enter our user id and password.

```
What is your username?:
```

here I can either enter my user id or just press enter to continue. I would like to know how to do it both ways. Finally it asks for the password.

`Password:`

then I enter the password. Trick here is that sometimes it let's me login by only entering the password once, but sometime it asks for the password multiple times.

How can I provide these answers in a simple text file and pass this file to shell script as an argument maybe that it can detect which question is being asked and provide answers based on what question is being asked. I would really appreciate if I can get some guidance on this one.

Comment: This would be a fairly complicated project.  You might do better by reading the script to see what it actually does with your responses, and execute those commands directly.

Comment: Check out [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or its grandpa [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). They let you match text and send input.

Comment: Note that a *well-designed* script will let you pass in answers through the environment, a config file, or some other mechanism other than prompting stdin. Make sure there isn't already an upstream-supported better approach before doing the work of building an `expect` script.

Comment: Does the admin actually want you scripting your connections? Is the input random specifically to prevent you doing this sort of thing? Perhaps ask them if there's a supported way to script your connections.

Comment: as others have pointed out u may need to use a [tag:expect]-like tool. if u r more comfortable with shell scripts, take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: thanks for the guidance everyone, I will look into these options.